# How do I repair .Net Framework from Basic MSI project in Installshield?

Tags: installation, installshield

I am working on basic MSI project in installshield for one WPF application.

I have added pre-requisite for .Net Framework, but this pre-requisite installs .Net framework according to registry value of .Net.

But my problem is, if .Net Framework is corrupted on user's machine, then how do i detect if it is corrupted or not and how do i repair it while installation.

Please suggest me solution for this asap.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you detect that the framework is corrupted outside of the installation? If you have a programmatic approach for that, perhaps it can be done by the installation. But I don't know how you'd detect such a thing to begin with.

Comment: That is the main issue. How do I detect if .Net is corrupted or not.

There is one tool ".Net Varification Tool", but it is also not accurate. And if any how I can find out if .Net is currupted, how do I repair it through pre-requisite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Installer has a mutex that enforces one installation per machine.  So even if you had code to detect a broken framework, you wouldn't be able to start the repair.

What's the origin of this requirement anyways?  IMO it shouldn't be your problem if the user has a broken framework.  Point them to the verification tool and let them figure it out.